# Failed to install webpack with npm in a project managed by lerna

Tags: webpack, npm-install, lerna

This is the relevant error message.

```
$ npm install webpack --save
npm ERR! While resolving: @h3/report@4.3.3-alpha.35
npm ERR! Found: @h3/awesome-ui@3.1.34
npm ERR! node_modules/@h3/awesome-ui
npm ERR!   @h3/awesome-ui@"3.1.34" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @h3/awesome-ui@"^4.2.3-alpha.36" from @h3/report@4.3.3-alpha.35
npm ERR! node_modules/@h3/report
npm ERR!   @h3/report@"4.3.3-alpha.35" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @h3/awesome-ui@4.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@h3/awesome-ui
npm ERR!   peer @h3/awesome-ui@"^4.2.3-alpha.36" from @h3/report@4.3.3-alpha.35
npm ERR!   node_modules/@h3/report
npm ERR!     @h3/report@"4.3.3-alpha.35" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I executed the command in the root directory. What does "xxx from the root project" mean here?

I have tried both --force and --legacy-peer-deps, but they failed.